# How can you pass events from a UserControl to one of its children?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, eventhandler

Assume you have a `UserControl` called `ActionableListBox` which is composed of a `DockPanel` that contains a `Button` and a `ListBox`.

Setting up `ActionableListBox` to expose the properties on the wrapped `ListBox` is simple. Just define the property on `ActionableListBox` and delegate the getter/setter down to the internal `ListBox`. Pretty straight forward.

What I'm not finding however is how to set up the `ActionableListBox` to 'pass thru' the events like `SelectionChanged`, etc. so I can use it in XAML. You can't 'delegate down' like with properties as an event handler can only appear on the left of an assignment operator.

So, short of being forced to convert this into a full-on `CustomControl`, is there any way to 'pass thru' the events so I can use this `UserControl` in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Define SelectionChanged event for ActionableListBox. For `ListBox`'s `SelectionChanged` create an event handler in `ActionableListBox` that in turn fires its own `SelectionChanged`.

```
    public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;
    ...
    listBox.SelectionChanged += listBox_SelectionChanged;
    ...
    void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
```

Comment: [head-slap] Duh!  It was right there!  Thanks!  Late night. Brain's not working! :)